# User rights: Only create, edit and publish articles

Tags: 7

There is a user role where users can edit, save and publish articles. But they don't see the admin menu.

Does exist a module to realize a "create content" button only or to modify the admin menu?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific module for that, and it is well known problem. But if you want them to only create one content type, like Article, you don't need a module for that. You can simply go to */admin/structure/menu* and add links like */node/add/page* to a menu they can access.

For node listings for such users, create a [view](https://drupal.org/project/views) with table of titles and edit links.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use a specific role for content creation but do not want them to get into any of the administration areas, I'd recommend the [Workbench](https://drupal.org/project/workbench) module. Create a new role called something like "Content Moderator" then in Workbench you can specify which content types they can add, edit, delete, and publish.