# Set up login to open a specific view

Tags: users

I [created a page view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/100549/16495) where user only get articles to edit.

How can I set up the page that it opened when a user logged in?

Comment: If I understand the question right, it's a dup of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19110/how-do-i-redirect-users-to-a-predetermined-url-after-login

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for functionality that is available in some ready modules. [Login Destination](https://drupal.org/project/login_destination) looks like a solid bet:

> The [Login Destination](https://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module allows you to customize the destination that a user is redirected to after logging in, registering to the site (7.x), using a one-time login link or logging out (7.x). The destination can be an internal page or an external URL. It is possible to specify certain conditions like referring pages or user roles and make the destination depend upon them.

Seems to be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The [Front Page](https://drupal.org/project/front) module will also handle this.  You can specify one page for anonymous user role and another page for authenticated user role so they get directed to that page after login.

You can also use Rules by specifying an Event of "User has logged in" then doing a "Page redirect" in the Actions.